# Error in Analysing data stream using twitter data in Spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark, spark-streaming, twitter-oauth, twitter4j

The error am getting is given below. [I'm using Scala to filter the Popular hashtags of twitter App Data stream. Please anyone could u direct me how to fix it?

```
Using Spark's default log4j profile: org/apache/spark/log4j-defaults.properties
Setting default log level to "WARN".
To adjust logging level use sc.setLogLevel(newLevel). For SparkR, use setLogLevel(newLevel).
SLF4J: Class path contains multiple SLF4J bindings.
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/C:/Users/begna/Desktop/Desktop/jar_files%20(1)%20all%20dependency/slf4j-log4j12-1.7.10.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/C:/spark/jars/slf4j-log4j12-1.7.16.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#multiple_bindings for an explanation.
SLF4J: Actual binding is of type [org.slf4j.impl.Log4jLoggerFactory]
Using Spark's default log4j profile: org/apache/spark/log4j-defaults.properties
18/03/26 15:43:48 INFO StreamingExamples: Setting log level to [WARN] for streaming example. To override add a custom log4j.properties to the classpath.
18/03/26 15:43:48 WARN NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
18/03/26 15:43:54 WARN Utils: Service 'SparkUI' could not bind on port 4040. Attempting port 4041.
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError: class org.apache.spark.streaming.scheduler.StreamingListenerBus has interface org.apache.spark.scheduler.SparkListener as super class
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.scheduler.JobScheduler.<init>(JobScheduler.scala:56)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.StreamingContext.<init>(StreamingContext.scala:183)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.StreamingContext.<init>(StreamingContext.scala:84)
    at twitterPopularTags$.main(twitterPopularTags.scala:60)
    at twitterPopularTags.main(twitterPopularTags.scala)
```

Comment: @ begna without a look at actual code it will be hard to guess , but looking at your error u can see 18/03/26 15:43:54 WARN Utils: Service 'SparkUI' could not bind on port 4040. Attempting port 4041.
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError: class org.apache.spark.streaming.scheduler.StreamingListenerBus has interface org.apache.spark.scheduler.SparkListener as super class
, i think spark is not able to start properly over the port 4040,also plz look at them they might help https://github.com/databricks/spark-csv/issues/44

Comment: @rajNishKuMar Thank for your help.Here the port number is not the problem it happened because I was running two spark application.

Comment: @rajNishKuMar Here am using the same code:https://github.com/eBay/Spark/blob/master/examples/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/examples/streaming/TwitterPopularTags.scala

Comment: Na not solved @rajNishKuMar  Please check once the Code:https://github.com/eBay/Spark/blob/master/examples/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/examples/streaming/TwitterPopularTags.scala

Comment: any solution for this issue ?